# Why we need to configure and deploy an ActiveMQ Queue to JBoss?

Tags: spring, jboss, activemq-classic

For sending and receiving messages we use apache activemq which is open source.activemq is integrated with jboss to perform this operation.But I want to know without integrating into jboss can we achieve this functionality , secondly why we need to use jboss integration with activemq.
I want to refine the question like what is the best practice for sending and receiving message using active mq and spring.
1) Is it like integrate the active mq with jboss and spring for the functionality
2) Use standalone like active mq with spring no jboss integration required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question; you want to know if you can send/receive messages without JBoss. Correct?

Yes, you can send/receive messages to/from ActiveMQ without JBoss by using even a standalone producer/consumer. JBoss in a Java EE spec server that provides many features.

If my answer doesn't help, you may want to provide a high level architecture and the problem you are trying to solve/understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the ActiveMQ rar file on JBoss.  Note that by default, this will attempt to start an embedded broker.  This can be disabled by removing the configuration section in the META-INF/ra.xml file.

Once deployed, you now have the ActiveMQ JCA running on JBoss.  In the JBoss configuration files, use a serverURL that points to your remote ActiveMQ instance.